# Normalization of a curve and push forward of vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, normalization

Let $C$ be a projective curve (over an algebraically closed field, not necessarily of characteristic zero) which is smooth except for exact one node. Let $\pi:\tilde{C} \to C$ be its normalization. Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a locally free sheaf over $\tilde{C}$. Is it true that the push forward, $\pi_*(\mathcal{V})$ is a locally free sheaf? If not, are there any general conditions (for example on the rank of $\mathcal{V}$) so that this holds true?

Comment: No and yes for the rank zero vector bundle. This question does not belong on mathoverflow IMHO.

Comment: @answer_bot: I do not understand why this question does not belong to mathoverflows when there is a similar question with 6 votes: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/67387/when-is-the-pushforward-of-a-vector-bundle-still-a-vector-bundle

Comment: @answer_bot: Anyways, could you please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: @user45397 The "similar" question is not restricted to curves and their normalizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting answer_bot: "No and yes for the rank zero vector bundle."  In other words, the answer is "no" except for one case: the rank zero vector bundle.  That means the answer is already "no" for *every* rank 1 vector bundle.  To user46578, I recommend that you contemplate what happens for the trivial rank 1 vector bundle on $\widetilde{C}$.  If you still have trouble, perhaps you should ask on Math StackExchange.

Comment: @Starr: Thank you very much for the answer.